# Google Sheet Query complaining of Column with date value having no date value - is this a bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-sheets

I have the following (simplified from original) formula which pulls in data from another sheet (multiple sheets in the original formula) and calculates the sum of a column based on the month() value of another column:

```
=QUERY({
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!$B$5, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L1000"), {"",TO_DATE(0),"","","","","","","","","",""})},
"SELECT SUM(Col8) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL AND month(Col2)+1="& MONTH($A3) &" AND Col1="""&B$2&""""& IF(NOT($C$1="ALL"), "AND Col6="""&$C$1&"""" ,)&  " label SUM(Col8) ''",0)
```

I keep getting the *#VALUE!* Error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Can't
> perform the function month on a column that is not a Date or a
> DateTime column

If I remove the `IFERROR` wrapper to the `IMPORTRANGE` statement then the error goes away and as you can see, in the case of an error on the `IMPORTRANGE` statement, an empty array with *Col2* set as a date with `TO_DATE(0)` is inserted.

This formula without the `IFERROR` works fine, and pulls in rows and provides a `SUM` value:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE('C1'!$B$5, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L1000")},"SELECT SUM(Col8) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL AND month(Col2)+1="& MONTH($A3) &" AND Col1="""&B$2&""""& IF(NOT($C$1="ALL"), "AND Col6="""&$C$1&"""" ,)&  " label SUM(Col8) ''",0)
```

Here's a link to a sample sheet that the formula imports from with the same structure of data: [Sample Sheet Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kIanrbngekb8G-9OU6Wkzq2LvhLSRuoLWNJld_BNyAg/edit?usp=sharing)

If the `Query` works without the `IFERROR` wrapper, why does it produce the error about *Col2* with the `IFERROR` wrapper in place which shouldn't be triggered in this case? This exact same formula works fine on another user's spreadsheet. Is this a Google Sheets/Query bug or is there something I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide in your question the comple formula that works and the one that does not? Also providing a sample spreadsheet would help troubleshooting.

Comment: @ziganotschka I've added the formula that works but unfortunately I'm not able to provide a sample spreadsheet that works as it would include financial data. Thanks

Comment: You can provide a dummy spreadsheet with fake values as long as it has the same formatting.

Comment: @ziganotschka I've now updated the question with a link to sample data.

Answer (score 1):

### `IFERROR(exp1,exp2)` is equivalent to `IF(NOT(ISERROR(exp1)),exp1,exp2)`

However, while the first option is not always compatible with queries, the second is more so.

In your case changing

`IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE('C1'!$B$5, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L1000"), {"",TO_DATE(0),"","","","","","","","","",""}`

to

`IF(NOT(ISERROR(importrange('C1'!$B$5, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L1000"))),importrange('C1'!$B$5, "PLACEMENTS!A4:L1000"), {"",TO_DATE(0),"","","","","","","","","",""})`

will solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for reply with solution. I used your amended formula and it does indeed work although other errors then cropped up when the IMPORTRANGE didn't pull in any useable data.I've used a different formula now which make separate queries for each external sheet and wraps them individually with an IFERROR and them using a SUM on all of them which seems to work. Out of curiosity - why is the variation you gave more "compatible" with queries?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer the "why" - it must be related to the implementation of the formula in the background - but I noticed already in the past that `IFERROR` often does not work combined with other formulas, especially array formulas. I hope the workaorund is useful for you, even if I cannot explain you the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have not shared the Sheet Snapshot you're working on, and it is hard to know what is happening in your formula.</strike>

### Answer Updated

`IFERROR` function is giving `{"",TO_DATE(0),"","","","","","","","","",""}` incase first parameter is false and that is the array which is generating the error.

In the *Query* function in *Select* clause, you're doing `Sum(Col8)` which need a number for summation, but in array, at location 8 you're giving an empty string. You just need to add zero at index 8 `{"",TO_DATE(0),"","","","","",0,"","","",""}`

Comment: The formula for 'C1'!$B$5 is in fact a cell reference to a valid sheet ID and works fine. Similarly, the double quotes are necessary since I'm breaking in and out of query statements with an IF clause. I've updated the main question with a link to sample data.

Comment: Thanks for updating answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem. As far as I can tell, the `IFERROR` shouldn't be "activated" anyway because the `IMPORTRANGE` does complete without error. It's strange therefore that I'm getting the error about Col2. Adding 0 at location 8 also makes no difference.

Comment: Then check same column from where data is being imported if there is any value in column 8 that is not date...